# Equally space 12 UIButtons using auto layout in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, storyboard

How to equally space these 12 buttons to fit all iPhone screens using auto layout ?

[image]

All buttons should be of same size and should completely fill the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Set spacing between buttons to 0 in both axis
- Bind top buttons row top constraint to the view top
- Bind bottom buttons row bottom constraint to the view bottom
- Bind left most column button leading constraint to the view leading
- Bind right most column button trailing constraint to the view trailing
- Set all buttons to have equal width and height, I think the easiest way to do this is to choose one button and then create constraints on all other buttons for equal width and equal height.

Also, nice thing about this setup is that if you change the number of rows or columns you will still end up with the buttons of identical sizes, so it's maintainable.

Comment: Thank  you so much .:)

Answer (score 0):

Add spacing between them to be 0 (leading, trailing, top, bottom). Then for each button set to have equal width and height as parent view with multiplier of 0.25 for height and 0.33 for width.

Comment: can be please elaborate more. !

Comment: Not gonna work on all devices because, for example, iPhone4 has different width/height ratio than iPhone5 etc. so your multipliers are wrong for some devices.

Comment: Multipliers are fine (three in row - 1/3 of width and 4 rows - 1/4 of height)

Comment: True, my bad, however I think it's easier to set equal width/height on each button and let the Autolayout resolve it for you, than set these multipliers for each constraint. Also, by setting equal heights and widths you can then change the number of rows or columns and you will still have buttons with identical sizes.